# Kenmore Elite Heavy Duty Quiet Pack 1 Dryer won't heat up

Tags: heating, dryer

Model # 110 63032101. It runs and blows, but doesn't heat. I checked the coil and verified there is continuity. There are 2 other devices hooked up near the heating coil, but I don't know what they are. Probably a thermometer? I reseated their connections. I also vacuumed all the dust I could. Here are the photos.

[image: heating element]
[image: 1st component - attached to the heating element enclosure]
[image: 2nd component - attached to heating element enclosure]
[image: 2nd component]
[image: 2nd component]
[image: 2nd component]
[image: 2nd component]

Also, the belt seems to have suddenly grew 4 inches and is now loose. It is not broken. There are only 2 pulleys so I don't know how it was taught before.

Comment: Are you getting both legs of 240V to the supply receptacle?  If you were only getting one leg (L1 and neutral, say) most things would work but it wouldn't heat up.

Comment: I plugged it in half way and 1 prong had 119V and the other prong had 120V.